# ClamAV, cannot update database, "cli_cvdverify: MD5 verification error" from debug

Tags: 18.04, database, clamav

I have two issues regarding ClamAV for Ubuntu 18.04.

**Note:** I originally posted the question at: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamav/+question/691247

1) When trying to update the database, it throws an error:

```
$ freshclam

ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
ERROR: Initialization error!
```

2) If updating manually,

```
$ sudo systemctl stop clamav-freshclam
$ sudo freshclam -v --debug
```

I get: "LibClamAV debug: cli_cvdverify: MD5 verification error"

```
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> ClamAV update process started at Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *Current working dir is /var/lib/clamav/
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *Querying current.cvd.clamav.net
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *TTL: 49
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *fc_dns_query_update_info: Software version from DNS: 0.102.3
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *Current working dir is /var/lib/clamav/
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *check_for_new_database_version: No local copy of "daily" database.
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *query_remote_database_version: daily.cvd version from DNS: 25838
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> daily database available for download (remote version: 25838)
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *Retrieving https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *downloadFile: Download source: https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Wed Jun 10 03:18:21 2020 -> *downloadFile: Download destination: /var/lib/clamav/tmp.8992e/clamav-ec18132f673c1d2a6bbeb5ec44d0ddce.tmp
* Trying 104.16.218.84...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to database.clamav.net (104.16.218.84) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
* subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
* start date: Apr 6 00:00:00 2020 GMT
* expire date: Oct 9 12:00:00 2020 GMT
* subjectAltName: host "database.clamav.net" matched cert's "database.clamav.net"
* issuer: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=CloudFlare, Inc.; CN=CloudFlare Inc ECC CA-2
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /daily.cvd HTTP/1.1
Host: database.clamav.net
User-Agent: ClamAV/0.102.3 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64)
Accept: */*
Connection: close

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 09:18:21 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 69709942
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=ddec765464d79c5d357514b14980f905f1591780701; expires=Fri, 10-Jul-20 09:18:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.clamav.net; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 12:50:00 GMT
< ETag: "5edf8578-427b076"
< Expires: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 13:18:21 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< Age: 11407
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< cf-request-id: 033f1f0d3b000011a51a284200000001
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 5a12012858e611a5-MIA
<
Time: 10.1s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 66.48MiB/66.48MiB
* Closing connection 0
LibClamAV debug: Initialized 0.102.3 engine
LibClamAV debug: in cli_cvdload()
LibClamAV debug: MD5(.tar.gz) = 2262f0af8e8aa108fa762edb971de51c
LibClamAV debug: cli_cvdverify: MD5 verification error
LibClamAV debug: Cleaning up phishcheck
LibClamAV debug: Phishcheck cleaned up
Wed Jun 10 03:18:31 2020 -> !getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity
Wed Jun 10 03:18:31 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> *check_for_new_database_version: No local copy of "daily" database.
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> *query_remote_database_version: daily.cvd version from DNS: 25838
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> daily database available for download (remote version: 25838)
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> *Retrieving https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> *downloadFile: Download source: https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Wed Jun 10 03:18:36 2020 -> *downloadFile: Download destination: /var/lib/clamav/tmp.8992e/clamav-ac9d70def64f50de9067f084f60e2eec.tmp


* Trying 104.16.218.84...

* Trying 104.16.218.84...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to database.clamav.net (104.16.218.84) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
* subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
* start date: Apr 6 00:00:00 2020 GMT
* expire date: Oct 9 12:00:00 2020 GMT
* subjectAltName: host "database.clamav.net" matched cert's "database.clamav.net"
* issuer: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=CloudFlare, Inc.; CN=CloudFlare Inc ECC CA-2
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /daily.cvd HTTP/1.1
Host: database.clamav.net
User-Agent: ClamAV/0.102.3 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64)
Accept: */*
Connection: close

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 09:20:34 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 69709942
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df95e600bf2a98f926903249460d7f8431591780834; expires=Fri, 10-Jul-20 09:20:34 GMT; path=/; domain=.clamav.net; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 12:50:00 GMT
< ETag: "5edf8578-427b076"
< Expires: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 13:20:34 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< Age: 11540
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< cf-request-id: 033f2116770000c88f880a6200000001
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 5a12046a5931c88f-MIA
<
Time: 10.8s, ETA: 0.0s [=============================>] 66.48MiB/66.48MiB
* Closing connection 0
LibClamAV debug: Initialized 0.102.3 engine
LibClamAV debug: in cli_cvdload()
LibClamAV debug: MD5(.tar.gz) = cd177dacb5343e60e3f8c3240dbf8175
LibClamAV debug: cli_cvdverify: MD5 verification error
LibClamAV debug: Cleaning up phishcheck
LibClamAV debug: Phishcheck cleaned up
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> !getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> Giving up on https://database.clamav.net...
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> !Update failed for database: daily
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> ^fc_update_databases: fc_update_database failed: Invalid or corrupted CVD/CLD database (7)
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> !Database update process failed: Invalid or corrupted CVD/CLD database (7)
Wed Jun 10 03:20:45 2020 -> !Update failed.
```

This is in a Ubuntu 18.04 distro.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

$ uname -r
5.3.0-53-generic

$ freshclam --version
ClamAV 0.102.3
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you retry now, there is a new version `25839` & please [edit] mistypes freshman to freshclam

Comment: Ok, I will try in a moment. Thank you for pointing out the typos.

Comment: Same result. I get to see `daily database available for download (remote version: 25839)`, but later the debug throws `cli_cvdverify: MD5 verification error` and `!getcvd: Verification: Can't verify database integrity`.

Comment: You can try to delete the old definition files in `/var/lib/clamav` then run `freshclam` again. Some others have solved same issue like this.For a manual update, find official cvd files here https://www.clamav.net/downloads#collapseCVD

Comment: The directory `/var/lib/clamav` is empty.

Comment: But then again, there must be a reason as to why the verification fails.

In [https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav-devel/blob/dev/0.102.3/libclamav/cvd.c] , there is this line of code where it goes to true and triggers the error message:

 `if (strncmp(md5, cvd->md5, 32)) `

Comment: The `md5` is being generated, but I cannot tell about `cvd->md5` if it is null or empty which seems the case if `strncmp` yields `true`.